# Is it a good idea to create a custom exception that I expect to be handled?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, exception

Is it a good idea to create a custom exception that would be thrown when an applicaiton logic fails which is expect to be handled?

Better to return an object or a value instead, I guess; but:

***If not***, then what is the correct conditions to introduce some custom exceptions into our code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is, assuming the issue you want to create it for is indeed an **exceptional** situation (i.e. should rarely happen, if ever).

If it is a normal error condition (something that you expect *will* happen on a regular basis and is part of normal usage of the application), you should code for it explicitly - in this case, creating and throwing a custom exception is a code smell.

Additionally, only create a custom exception if it adds information (over the built in ones).

---

**Edit:** (following comments)

Using exception handling as a form of flow control (i.e. did function X complete correctly or not) is pretty much *always* a bad idea and is a *definite* code smell.

Comment: Oded, Can you possibly open this a bit more; what I wanted to stress here is to misuse the exception in a way that it is an optional way to return some other information instead. Like an alternative to the real return type of the method. Did you get my meaning?

Comment: Ok! Now I got your point. Your edit of your answer is more clear to me now. ;) Thanks!

Comment: I and many others disagree with you that exceptions are only used for exceptional things.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own custom exceptions when you expect to perform an action based on the type of exception being thrown.  If your purpose is to show the user a message then the type of exception being thrown means very little.

However, you need to be careful when you create your own exception types because there are many very good exception types already in the .NET platform and you should use one of those first.  It's much better to have a FileNotFound exception as opposed to JoesBestFileNotFound exception.

Comment: I would suggest the opposite: if a `DocumentLoad` method throws a `DocumentFileNotFound` exception when it fails to load a document, then code which catches that exception can know that the document couldn't be loaded because the *document* file wasn't found.  By contrast, if one merely threw `FileNotFoundException`, calling code wouldn't know whether the document file couldn't be found, or a DLL, configuration file, or other such thing couldn't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can get by with standard exceptions.  If you want to provide more useful debugging information the boost stuff could help.

You want to create your own exceptions when you want to provide information that goes beyond what the other options give you or when you want the user to be able to handle it in a unique manner.  If all you're doing is mentioning that there is an exceptional situation then just use the wheel's that are already there to use.

I suggest always inheriting from std::exception or one of its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best practice to code without the possibility for exceptions to be thrown in the first place. If you need a reason: They're slow. Quantifiably slower than coding around them in even the most inelegant ways in most cases. That being said, sometimes they are unavoidable because of the code other people have written or they are desired because you really do want the program to blow up in the face of the user (see catastrophic failure). Only in these two cases is exception handling the way to go.

But this doesn't mean you wrap every `IEnumerable<T>.First()` in an `if(sequence.Count() > 0)`. Learn to structure your code soundly, such that you don't ever call the `.First()` on an empty sequence in the first place. Elegant code is win.

I recently wrote a quick app for my employer to be used in an automated system (where the user does not sit at the keyboard) that **must** require the user to enter login information in command line args (think batch file) or a config file else it intentionally blows up in their face, as per spec. In this case, an exception is warranted.

All the code below demonstrates my philosophy on Exceptions.

```
    private static string _password;
    public static string Password
    {
        get
        {
            if (_password.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
                throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("{0} {1}",
                    "Password was neither found in the .cfg file nor the",
                    "command line arguments."));
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
            _password = value ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

An example of coding without exceptions in this extension method I just wrote.

```
    public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, T, bool> func)
    {
        if (list.Count() < 2)
            return true;

        T first = list.First();

        return list.Skip(1).Aggregate(true, (i, k) => i && func(first,k));
    }
```

Notice below I dealt with I/O Exceptions within the scope of the I/O method, but I parsed the data in the config file in such a way that **my** logic will never throw an exception. Note how The .Count() is verified to be 2 in all pieces of data. At this point, I can be confident that .First() and .Last() will not only be valid to the compilier and not throw exceptions, but be guaranteed to yield potentially valid pieces of data (non-whitespace, different values). This is the kind of philosophy I recommend you adapt when you think about Exception handling -> *How do I filter and control my data in a referentially transparent way to completely eliminate errors within the scope of the method?*

```
public static class ConfigParser
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> PullFromConfigFile()
    {
        ParallelQuery<Tuple<string, string>> data;

        try
        {
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("config.cfg");

            data = tr.ReadToEnd()
                .Split('\n')
                .AsParallel()

                .Select(i => new string(i.TakeWhile(k => k != '#').ToArray()))
                .Where(i => !i.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())

                .Select(i => i.Split('\t')
                    .Where(k => !k.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
                    .Select(k => k.Trim())
                )
                .Where(i => i.Count() == 2)
                .Select(i => new Tuple<string, string>(i.First(), i.Last()));

            tr.Close();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            Logger.Bad("config.cfg file was not found");
            return new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        return ConfigParser.ParseIntoDict(data);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> ParseIntoDict(ParallelQuery<Tuple<string, string>> data)
    {
        var agg = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var entry in data)
        {
            if (!agg.ContainsKey(entry.Item1))
                agg.Add(entry.Item1, entry.Item2);
        }

        var width = agg.Keys.Max(k => k.Length);
        agg.ForAll(i => Logger.Log("Loaded Data: {0} {1}",
            i.Key.SetWidth(width, '-'), i.Value));

        return agg;
    }
}
```

Extensions used:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string SetWidth(this string item, int width, char padder, bool right = true)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return new string(padder, width);

        if (width > item.Length)
            return right ? item.PadRight(width, padder) : item.PadLeft(width, padder);
        return item.Substring(0, width);
    }
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string str)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you shouldn't use exceptions for normal program logic. It's fine however to create exceptions for scenarios specific to your application. There's plenty of good advice out there for exception handling -- take for example this [MSDN exception design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) document for starters.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the .NET FW there are numerous `Exceptions` to specify certain conditions. `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `NotImplementedException`, etc... They all exist and are derived from Exception to deal with exceptional (pun not intended) cases.

Drawing the line between what to classify as an Exception versus simply returning null for instance can often times become gray. Use your best judgement and try to remain constant within the team on that judgement.